# Kotlin Android error messages, but app runs well

Tags: android, kotlin

My Android app written in Kotlin is ok to run, but Android Studio keeps showing a lot of errors. Can anyone help me solve it?

```
06-12 20:30:40.244 1500-11361/? E/AudioFlinger: not enough memory for AudioTrack size=131296
06-12 20:30:40.244 1500-11361/? E/AudioFlinger: createRecordTrack_l() initCheck failed -12; no control block?
06-12 20:30:40.244 2960-13595/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search E/AudioRecord: AudioFlinger could not create record track, status: -12
06-12 20:30:40.246 2960-13595/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search E/AudioRecord-JNI: Error creating AudioRecord instance: initialization check failed with status -12.
06-12 20:30:40.246 2960-13595/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search E/android.media.AudioRecord: Error code -20 when initializing native AudioRecord object.
06-12 20:30:45.283 1500-1808/? E/AudioFlinger: not enough memory for AudioTrack size=131296
06-12 20:30:45.284 1500-1808/? E/AudioFlinger: createRecordTrack_l() initCheck failed -12; no control block?
06-12 20:30:45.284 2960-13595/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search E/AudioRecord: AudioFlinger could not create record track, status: -12
06-12 20:30:45.285 2960-13595/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search E/AudioRecord-JNI: Error creating AudioRecord instance: initialization check failed with status -12.
06-12 20:30:45.285 2960-13595/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search E/android.media.AudioRecord: Error code -20 when initializing native AudioRecord object.
06-12 20:30:50.312 1500-1808/? E/AudioFlinger: not enough memory for AudioTrack size=131296
06-12 20:30:50.312 1500-1808/? E/AudioFlinger: createRecordTrack_l() initCheck failed -12; no control block?
06-12 20:30:50.312 2960-13595/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search E/AudioRecord: AudioFlinger could not create record track, status: -12
06-12 20:30:50.314 2960-13595/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search E/AudioRecord-JNI: Error creating AudioRecord instance: initialization check failed with status -12.
06-12 20:30:50.314 2960-13595/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search E/android.media.AudioRecord: Error code -20 when initializing native AudioRecord object.
06-12 20:30:55.347 1500-1808/? E/AudioFlinger: not enough memory for AudioTrack size=131296
06-12 20:30:55.347 1500-1808/? E/AudioFlinger: createRecordTrack_l() initCheck failed -12; no control block?
06-12 20:30:55.348 2960-13595/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search E/AudioRecord: AudioFlinger could not create record track, status: -12
06-12 20:30:55.349 2960-13595/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search E/AudioRecord-JNI: Error creating AudioRecord instance: initialization check failed with status -12.
06-12 20:30:55.349 2960-13595/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search E/android.media.AudioRecord: Error code -20 when initializing native AudioRecord object.
06-12 20:31:00.009 1664-1684/system_process E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
```

Comment: AudioFlinger is a system component and com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox (quick search bar) is triggering AudioRecord, so not related to your code, you're running most likely out of memory or revoked some permission. Just disable "ok google" detection.